# Inventor: How to replace static part with articulation?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, modeling, simulation, cad, autodesk-inventor

I have downloaded the following part file of a servo motor as IGES from the vendor:

[image]

I have then built an assembly that uses several of these motors, as well as a number of idlers/hubs, brackets, machine screws, and whatnot. I've used the standard "constrain mate to face" and "constrain mate axis" constraints, as well as inserting bolts from content center, and bolted connections for bolt+nut.

Now, as it turns out, the "horn" part of this servo (the aluminum wheel on the front with the eight threaded holes) is modeled as a static part of the mesh in the IGES file. But, in real live, this moves/articulates. I'd like my model to move/articulate the same as the real thing.

How can I get there with the minimum amount of re-work?

The closest I can think of right now is to break off the horn from the motor housing, and create two part files, then create a sub-assembly out of those part files, and then delete each of the motors in the bigger assembly and re-add them. Given the amount of constraints and bolt connections on those things, that would be about as bad as starting over from scratch.

Is there an easier/better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: If it suppose to articulate then yes you need to split it into two part files. But the connection should not be that bad. A simple pin joint would do it.

Comment: The problem is not creating the connection in the new assembly. The problem is replacing all the parts that are static in a large existing assembly, with references to this new assembly, where a lot of other parts are already constrainted to the motor or horn pieces.